# How to use Graph Edit Distances and the graph-level features at the same time

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a distance matrix between paris of graphs computed by Graph Edit Distances. Besides, I have also a group or class label for each graph. Besides, each graph is assigned a target value in real number. I want to do a knn to predict this target value as a regression problem. How can I use both the distance matrix and the class labels at the same time? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can flatten the matrix and one-hot-encode the label. But I think the number of features would get to large for KNN

Comment: @Janosch Thanks! I don't quite understand how to flatten the distance matrix? May you elaborate it please? Thanks!

Comment: [tag:gower-similarity]?